# Android - how do I run my app in the Nook emulator which I think I installed

Tags: android, nook, nook-tablet

I just went through the steps to install the NOOK packages from my sdk manager.

But what are the steps to actually run apps with the nook emulator?

I am going from these instructions, but they are a bit confusing:
https://nookdeveloper.zendesk.com/entries/21943338-nook-developer-start-up-guide#_SpecifyURL

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with running apps in the standard emulators (i.e. not Nook or any of the ones you need to download separately)?

Comment: @ataulm yes I have been testing my android app in the emulator for a while...but that is only with the standard emulator that I always had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's installed, can you not just run it from the Android Virtual Device manager (in Eclipse, this is found under `Window` > `Android Virtual Device Manager`), creating an instance of the Nook table using the new button.

[These instructions](https://nookdeveloper.zendesk.com/entries/21846516-quick-start-for-android-developers#_Using_Emulator) seem more followable, see section 3.1-2. It's funny how it's called "Quick Start" though.

[Section 3.3.3](https://nookdeveloper.zendesk.com/entries/21846516-quick-start-for-android-developers#_Eclipse_Starts_Emulator) deals specifically with running via Eclipse.

General emulator usage (assuming Eclipse):
Once the emulator has been created, and started, let it boot up completely, then run your app as an Android Application, choosing the running emulator as the target.

If not using Eclipse, then `adb install <file.apk>` via command line will install to the currently connected device or emulator if there is only one running/connected.

Comment: ah yes, thank you...going to window --> AVD showed only the main emulator on the main screen, BUT when I clicked on the device-definitions tab, it showed me the Nook tablet emulator.  How can I run that?

Comment: For future people with same issue, how did you run it? Created a new AVD based on that device definition?